# Fixing the "Duplicate 'Compile' items were included." error in Visual Studio

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

This is a very annoying VS error, I'm on VS 2019 16.8.1

I spend a lot of time fixing it:

> Duplicate 'Compile' items were included. The .NET SDK includes
> 'Compile' items from your project directory by default. You can either
> remove these items from your project file, or set the
> 'EnableDefaultCompileItems' property to 'false' if you want to
> explicitly include them in your project file. For more information,
> see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems. The duplicate items were:
> 'Program.cs'  Service.Host
> Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets    295

I can't understand what causes this error.
I commented out the `Include` tags in the *.csproj files, but the problem is that I have more than 30 projects, all of a sudden they all have the same duplicate error, going through all of them to fix such a mysterious error seems unsafe action, some of these projects are legacy projects that haven't been touched for a long time.
Another problem in the solution commenting the `Include` tags is that I have some project with this include structure:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Contracts.cs" />
    <Compile Include="IKey.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Contracts.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="ISigner.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Contracts.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
```

commenting this will affect the project structure.

I tried to comment out the `CheckForDuplicateItems` tags in the file:

"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets",

and the errors are gone.

EDIT

I just noticed that the .NET 5 version (..\sdk\5.0.101..) is included in the targets file path, I only have one project with .NET 5, does this cause the problem?

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET5 uses the new style projects which auto-include a number of files into your project. This helps keep the projects files small and doesn't cause them to be checked out and changed every time you add, remove or rename a file. Probably the easiest way to fix this for all projects at once is to add a `directory.build.props` in the root folder of your project to set the `<EnableDefaultCompileItems>false<EnableDefaultCompileItems>` for all projects at once.

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
         <EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Do not edit any files in the sdk directory, they are the default settings for all projects current and future. Instead you can add these settings to your project files or these directory of solution global files to change them for your projects in a specific folder or solution.

See:

- [Directory.Build.props and Directory.Build.targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets)
- [Default compilation includes in .NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511#default-compilation-includes-in-net-core-projects)

Comment: How is putting the "directory.build.props" in the project root will affect other projects?

Comment: It will automatically set this property for all projects without having to edit all the project files. Since it only changes the behavior of the .NET 5 projects, it won't change any behavior of your existing .NET 4 projects when built. When building a .NET 5 project or a .NET 5 project it will turn off the new default behavior and revert to how things were in .NET 4 for those projects.

Comment: `directory.build.props` will affect all proj file from the same level and the subdirectory. It's acting downwards. And the issue is as jessehouwing said, new sdk project dos not add compile, content, none items on the proj file. It will  automatically grab all the files in your project from time to time. It is a new freature for the new-sdk. Or you have to use `<EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems>` to disable the feature and then manually read items. Or, you have to delete any `Compile` items on your proj file.

Comment: @mshwf,If jessehouwing's answer helps you handle the issue, please do not forget to accept it. If not, please feel free to let us know:)

Answer (score 0):

Theo only solution that worked for me was excluding the `obj` folder from the project.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .cs file from csproj as they are automatically considered part of the project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).