# Prevent VS from adding explicit compile tags to csproj

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild, .net-standard

I am aware of .NET Core's change to the .csproj file, and how the GLOB automatically detects *.cs files, as [as documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511#default-compilation-includes-in-net-core-projects). However, the issue is I am still running into a certain error upon compile.

As documented in the above link, I keep getting the error:

> Duplicate Compile items were included. The .NET SDK includes Compile items from your project directory by default. You can either remove these items from your project file, or set the 'EnableDefaultCompileItems' property to 'false' if you want to explicitly include them in your project file.

My project is picking up all *.cs files perfectly fine within the project directory. However, whenever I ** ADD A NEW** class (right click >> add new item), the following is also added into the .csproj:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Base\Class1.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I know that simply removing this will prevent the error from occurring, since this explicit compile conflicts with the GLOB's implicit include. How can I stop this from happening?

### EDIT

Here is my .csproj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
        <LangVersion>8</LangVersion>
        <NeutralLanguage>en</NeutralLanguage>
        <Authors>Phillip Smith</Authors>
        <Company>Phillip Smith</Company>
        <Description>.Net Standard library to read and write .m64 files for Mupen64</Description>
        <PackageIcon>nugetIcon.png</PackageIcon>
        <PackageTags>mupen, n64, m64</PackageTags>
        <EnableNETAnalyzers>true</EnableNETAnalyzers>
        <PackageProjectUrl>https://github.com/TimeTravelPenguin/MupenSharp</PackageProjectUrl>
        <RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/TimeTravelPenguin/MupenSharp</RepositoryUrl>
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
        <Version>1.0.3.5</Version>
        <Copyright>Phillip Smith</Copyright>
        <PackageLicenseExpression></PackageLicenseExpression>
        <ApplicationIcon>icon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
        <DocumentationFile>D:\C#_Offline\MupenMovieEditor\MupenSharp\MupenSharp.xml</DocumentationFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="icon.ico" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="JetBrains.Annotations" Version="2020.3.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations">
            <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll</HintPath>
        </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="..\..\Images\nugetIcon.png">
            <Pack>True</Pack>
            <PackagePath></PackagePath>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Update="Resources\ExceptionsResource.Designer.cs">
            <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
            <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
            <DependentUpon>ExceptionsResource.resx</DependentUpon>
        </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\ExceptionsResource.resx">
            <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
            <LastGenOutput>ExceptionsResource.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
        </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

### EDIT 2

Video demonstration:

https://youtu.be/3ZU-Ue-goaE

Comment: Please let us know any further progress about your issue and we are willing to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

**new-sdk** project will automatically identify the type of file and then include it as an item in your project. So you don't have to define any items that are related to the file.

It is a new feature of new-sdk project.

Since you have defined your files through items under csproj file and want to use them without deleting these items, you should disable the automatic associated feature.

Add these under `csproj` file to disable it:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
         <EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

**Besides**, there is also [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65275700/fixing-the-duplicate-compile-items-were-included-error-in-visual-studio) you can check it.

**Update 1**

**Actually**, `EnableDefaultCompileItems` to `false` just disables the global lookup feature(disable implicit association) and avoid duplicate recognition of items----Use the old feature under Net framework projects.

You have to manually uses the items from your `csproj` to include any items. If you do not write any items to include files, VS will turn out errors. And the feature is to improve the function. The new-sdk projects enable such automatic feature to simplify the trouble for developers.

**Also**, if you use `EnableDefaultCompileItems` to `false`, some compile items which you have defined before as implicit files will miss because the automatic association function is turned off and does not leave any mark in `csproj`.

**However**, these files still exists under your project. In this situation, you have to click show all files on the solution explorer and then include them in your project.

[image]

=================================================

**Besides**, the new sdk projects with the global lookup feature cannot work with `compile include` node. This is the double repeat import file.

**In fact**, it still has an alternative solution.

You can use **update** node.

Directly Use this without `EnableDefaultCompileItems`:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Base\Class1.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**Note**: `update` is a feature of new-sdk projects and only works for those which are already detected globally and  found by the implicit association of the new-SDK project. If the files are not implicitly associated, then `update` will never work.

**In other words**, if the files you want to associate are outside the project (get rid of the implicit association of the project), then you can only use `include` to include these files from outside into inside projects, `update` only works for subsequent MSBuild operations as the implicitly associated file and this is equivalent to a supplement to the automatically associated files rather than re-importing, more likely an override operation.

`Update` acts on the inside project's files while `Include` acts on the outside
project's files.

That is different from `include` node.

> My project is picking up all *.cs files perfectly fine within the
> project directory. However, whenever I ** ADD A NEW** class (right
> click >> add new item), the following is also added into the .csproj:

That means you already have set `EnableDefaultCompileItems` to `false`. With this, your `csproj` will have this include node.

If you still have this issue, please share your csproj file with us to help us troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: I don't think this is right. By doing this, everything in my solution explorer disappears and no longer appears. My project no longer compiles. I believe this is because the default uses GLOB to find all the classes, which is the normal function. However, only recently has it been added my mentioned code to my csproj without my wanting.

Comment: I have a make a complete and comprehensive explanation for you. Please see my updated answer . And please check it.

Comment: Apologies for the delay; I have been very busy. I do not have these nodes present in my project. I have edited my question with my entire csproj. Note that I have this exact same issue with a BRAND NEW project.

Comment: @TimeTravelPenguin, I have no issue with your provided csproj file(I change it from non-sdk format into the new sdk format), See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUqAi.png). Also, this issue also happens on another project. So please whether your vs has something wrong.1) disable any third party extensions under `Extensions`-->`Manage Extensions`-->`Installed`. 2) use [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to start a pure VS and then test your project under it

Comment: 3) [repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019). Besides, you could try to share a reproducible sample with github with us and we can troubleshoot your issue more quickly. Any feedback will be expected.

Comment: I have already tried both a repair and full uninstall/reinstall. Here is a video demonstration: https://youtu.be/3ZU-Ue-goaE

Comment: I will check it.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I have the same issue that @TimeTravelPenguin details. His video exactly details my issue. This issue did not occur until VS 16.8. It even occurs in the very latest 16.9.0. I have disabled literally every VS extension, same issue. We do not want to set `EnableDefaultCompileItems` to `false`. Instead, we want VS to not add the unnecessary Compile elements to our csproj. I have [exported my VS settings so that may be inspected as well](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MUOuuybFiaccIulNQfzWoOWdJiMtNbXB/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: I have added [Visual Studio feedback](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/compile-elements-added-to-project-file-when-enable/1356490?from=email) for this issue.

Comment: @Adam-Caviness thank you, please keep us posted on any updates as I have still not resolved the issue

Comment: @TimeTravelPenguin I'm not getting any traction on my [VS issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/compile-elements-added-to-project-file-when-enable/1356490?from=email&viewtype=all). Would you be willing to comment or contribute to the discussion? Thanks.

Comment: @TimeTravelPenguin It seems as though we have [another individual experiencing this issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/compile-elements-added-to-project-file-when-enable/1356490#T-N1412147).

Comment: Recently this issue has disappeared for me. In visual studio, I went to the ReSharper tool menu, and select uninstall. Then, I installed ReSharper from the JetBrains toolbox (I originally had it installed via JetBrain's dotUltimate. I have had no instance of this issue since! There are instances of glitchiness when I add a .txt file as Resource (NOT Embedded Resource). Then it sometimes removes the item.

Comment: @TimeTravelPenguin I am no longer able to reproduce this issue in VS 16.10.0 RTW.

Comment: @AdamCaviness That is awesome! I am updating now. Recently, the issue has returned, so this is hopefully the beginning of the end of this terrible issue!!